# Can't stop list dividers being treated as list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function() {alert("A list item was clicked");}
```

I'm using the above code to perform an action on every list item but list dividers are also proccing this event.

I managed to exclude my close button using

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function() {
    if (this.id !== "closeButton") {
        alert("A list item was clicked");
    }
});
```

however I can't stop it from occurring on list dividers. I've tried to no avail

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function() {
    if (this.class !== "ui-li-divider") {
        alert("A list item was clicked");
    }
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle with the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2g3w5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify your selector to `li:not([data-role='list-divider'])`

```
$(document).on("click", "li:not([data-role='list-divider'])", function() {
    if (this.id !== "closeButton") {
        alert("A list item was clicked");
        //choosePageTypeToBuild();
   }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2g3w5/2/)

**OR** modify your selector to `li:not([data-role='list-divider'], #closeButton)` and get rid of `if` condition

```
$(document).on("click", "li:not([data-role='list-divider'], #closeButton)", function() {
    alert("A list item was clicked"); //Get rid of if condition
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2g3w5/4/)

Also, make sure you use specific selectors, else the selector you are using will target ALL the `li` elements in your document.

So assign an `id` to the wrapper element and modify your selector accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Use a *flag* class on items which are not clickable & change you script to this,

Here I am using `'stat'` class as flag

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('stat')){
        alert("A list item was clicked");
   }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2g3w5/1/)

Answer (score 1):

because your divider is a 'li' element,
Edit "li" -> "a" and see what happen

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
    if (this.class !== "ui-li-divider") {
        alert("A list item was clicked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the `data-role` attribute too and find out that the item is not a `list-divider`

The sample code will be something like this

```
 $(document).on("click", "li", function () {
    if ($(this).attr('data-role') !== 'list-divider' && this.id !== "closeButton") {
        alert("A list item was clicked");

    }

});
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shivasaxena/2g3w5/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `:not` in jquery

```
$(document).on("click", "li:not('.ui-li-divider')", function() {
        alert("A list item was clicked");
        //choosePageTypeToBuild();
});
```

or check with `hasClass` in jquery

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("ui-li-divider")) {
        alert("A list item was clicked");
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2g3w5/6/)